# Log Android SQLite queries with bound parameters

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-log

Right now, I can only log statements like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?;
```

Is there a way to log SQLite queries after their parameters have been bound? So the queries look more like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '3';
```

Comment: you probably can use `SQLiteQueryBuilder` instead of plain strings

Comment: I am, in places, but it doesn't seem to log the query any more completely.

Comment: it can, if you log `buildQuery` with the same parameters as for the `query` call.

Comment: Ah, I found the an isLoggable() wrapper around that. Still, this will only work for queries using the QueryBuilder yes? I'm trying to analyze existing queries, not all of which use a builder.

Comment: yes. You may have to refactor to use querybuilders.

Comment: Not going to happen.  However if you create a provider with a private db you could easily log the crud going to the provider.